# Unable to boot into Ubuntu, after changing to Windows for 2 weeks

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, bios

I've dual-booted my Windows 10 machine with Ubuntu 18.04 for 2 years now, and I recently updated it to 20.04. Everything was going well until I recently switched to Windows entirely for two weeks after which it boots automatically into Windows at startup and ignores Ubuntu. Many of the answers that I see for similar problems are for those who've just dual-booted their systems and the answers ask them to use the Ubuntu USB or disk etc. to open Ubuntu and run commands there. But I'm unable to open Ubuntu. After seeing some answers, I tried the command `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` and turning off *fast startup* from the System Settings but to no avail. Can someone help out?

**EDIT:**
I've tried [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/374349/pc-boots-straight-into-windows-10-instead-of-launching-grub) out, and though I didn't find GRUB in the boot tab, I had **UEFI: ST2000ML007-1R8174, Partition 1** and I put it above the Windows Boot Manager and I saved the settings, but to no avail, again.

Comment: Has windows run any updates in the 2 weeks?

Comment: @David yes I think that's what's caused the settings to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try boot-repair if you haven't already, you don't necessarily need access to your ubuntu partition, just download a live distro like boot-repair-disk, burn it and make it boot as first device from bios. I had a similar issue (Mint 20 + Windows 10, both UEFI), running the tool with standard settings should make your grub screen appear again. Also, when selecting the grub menu entry for Windows remember to choose the one ending with 'bootmgfw.efi' or else (as it happened to me) the problem may occur again. Hope this helps

Comment: I ran the tool after burning and the problem seems to be solved. Though, at no point did I have to select a grub menu entry for Windows like you said. (to prevent future problems). I just opened the boot-repair-disk, it repaired and I did not have to choose anything anywhere. There was also some error during the boot repair, and it's report is here http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/52DbdhQtdj/

Comment: I received a similar warning but both systems seem to boot just fine, it has to do with UEFI/bios conflicting settings I think, probably someone here with more knowledge can explain it more in detail. As for the Windows UEFI menu entry in question, I was referring to the one presented in the grub screen, in my case selecting "Windows boot manager" would hide grub menu again at the next boot

Comment: I can't seem to face the hiding of grub menu problem that you describe, after several restarts. It's fine, I guess. Thanks!